# Count object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not my function in JavaScript (jQuery) return me (with console.log) object:

```
Object { 1=[3]}
```

or

```
Object { 2=[1]}
```

or

```
Object { 5=[5]}
```

etc. name object is random. How can i count values from this object? I dont know name of object. Count values is in [ ]. For my examples there are 3, 1 and 5.

i tried:

```
var test = OtherFunction();
alert(test.length);
```

but htis return me undefined.

Comment: So, the object looks actually like `{2: [1]}`?

Comment: Count the values meaning the number of keys the object has, or sum the values?

Comment: yes, but name (in your example 2) is random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over an object:

```
// iterates over all properties of your object
for (var i in obj){
   console.log(i);       // will give you the name of the key i
   console.log(obj[i]);  // will give you the value of the key i in the object
}
```

Now with this you can do whatever you want, count the keys, sum the values,...

Answer (score 6):

```
var obj = {foo: 'bar', foo2: 'bar2' /* etc */};
```

Modern way (won't work in old IEs)

```
console.log(Object.keys(obj).length); //2
```

Way that will work in older IEs:

```
var keys = 0;
for (var i in obj) keys++;
console.log(keys); //2
```

Comment: @Mark: Then you apparently don't want to count the keys. To me it seems that the object has one property which holds an array and you want to get the first value of that array. Or how do we have to interpret the output `Object { 1=[3]}`? Could you provide the object definition?